# How I can store checkbox value instead of true r false in Odoo

Tags: odoo

How I can store checkbox value instead of true r false in Odoo

```
example !  field1 = fields.Boolean('Value1')
       field2 = fields.Boolean('Value2')
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

With my personal experience you cannot store a value which does not match the field type. For your case storing something else in a Boolean field instead true or false means the field's type does not mean anything (like storing string in boolean).

So here is a kind of solutions:

1. You add another field char (lets say you want to store 'val1' for true and 'val2' for false) then you override the create method (and the write one) and check if your_boolean_field_value == true then your_char_field_value == 'val1' else your_boolean_field_value == false then your_char_field_value == 'val2', in your process you can the use your_boolean_field_value or your_char_field_value.
2. Another solution is to group your booleans using a selection field thus you can store strings, integers, floats as string.

Personally i'll go for the second solution because it uses a built-in principle.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You're right but client requires like this not selection type .
Actually i need to store multiple choices showing on GUI not in selection as requirement.
i will go your suggestion  Thanks